# Transparent background in world in whitestorm js?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a world that does not have a background so that I can add objects to it and then run this world over a background configured in html. Is something like this possible?

Here is a link to the [site](https://magnumsun.github.io/) I am working on. To clarify: I am trying to figure out how to make the black transparent so that the background behind it is visible. Here is the [repo](https://github.com/MagnumSun/MagnumSun.github.io). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use CSS for now instead.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
const world = new WHS.World({
  background: {
    opacity: 0; // Opacity is 0. Fully transparent
  },

  renderer: {
    alpha: true // Allow transparency in renderer.
  }
});
```

**UPDATE**
In v2.x.x use the following approach:

```
const app = new WHS.App([
  // ...
  new WHS.app.RenderingModule({
    bgOpacity: 0,

    renderer: {
      alpha: true
    }
  })
]);
```